# Jquery Trigger change event in safari

Tags: jquery, onchange, eventtrigger

Jquery Trigger Change event is not working in Safari browser only.

```
$("#set-default").val('').trigger('change');
```

Is there any alternate method for this. I need to reset the selectbox value dynamically.

Comment: I am sorry. I am using SELECT2 plugin. I am getting the proper result by using before code.$("#set-default").select2('val', '');    No need to trigger change event here.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reset the selected value in select2 then you can use this:

```
$("#set-default").select2('val', '');
```

you can trigger change by adding true

```
$("#set-default").select2('val', '', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that in `select2`:

```
$("#set-default").val(null).trigger("change");
```